# this sql seems to remove all rows that have a field above 0

Tags: mysql, sql

So basically I am trying to get an auto expiry going on my sales page, I have this sql;

```
DELETE 
FROM `game_sales` 
WHERE `expires` <= NOW() 
  AND `expires` > 0
```

It seems to remove all rows where `expires > 0` regardless of the `expires` being lower than the current time.

How can I stop this?

Comment: The query above is not removing anything from your db.  Look at your db log to see the actual delete clause that is getting invoked

Comment: Ooops i copied the wrong one, the right ones up

Comment: What's the data type of `expires`?

Comment: can you define your expires or it would be good if you add an example which records should be delete and which shouldn't

Comment: If `expires` is a unix timestamp, it will _always_ be <= NOW() because it will compare as a zero datetime.  You need to use `FROM_UNIXTIME(expires)`

Comment: @LiamDawe `Now()` returns a datetime value, not an integer. What are you expecting the value to be??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply cannot compare an `INT` with a `DATETIME` (which is what `NOW()` returns).

If your `expires` is in fact a timestamp, you can either:

- convert the timestamp to a `DATETIME` with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`: `WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(expires) <= NOW()`
- convert the the `DATETIME` to an integer: `WHERE expires <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())`

The second option is certainly to be preferred. With this version, most queries *should* be able to use an index on `expires` (whereas the first version *definitely* prevents usage of an index on this column).

Comment: Yes that's it exactly, I didn't even realise NOW() was a proper time format, thought it was a timestamp, that was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Query only selects data, it does not delete it. 
The WHERE condition gives back data that matches BOTH conditions, so I would look for your expires < NOW() statement.

`expires < NOW()` gives all entries where the expiredate is right before now

and

`expires > 0` gives you all expire values bigger than 0

edit: 
With the int time you already got the problem. 
`NOW()` returns a value in `datetime` datatype. 
Compared with int it should compare the millisecond value of your time.

Did you store your time in milliseconds?

Comment: as poster stated the column is of type INT